# 1D Lax-Friedrichs scheme leading error term

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

> The Lax-Friedrichs scheme for the 1D linear advection equation $$\frac{}{}+ _\frac{}{} = 0$$ with a
> constant flow speed of $_$ is
> $$(+Δ,)=\frac{1}{2}[(,+Δ)+(,−Δ)]−\frac{Δ_}{2Δ}[(,+Δ)−(,−Δ)]$$
> where $Δ$, $Δ$ and $_$ are the time step, the cell width of a 1D uniform mesh and the flow
> speed respectively. Applying Taylor series expansions of $(+Δ,)$, $(,+Δ)$ and
> $(,−Δ)$ about $(,)$, show that the leading error term (...) of the Lax-Friedrichs
> scheme is
> $$...=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{Δ^2}{Δ}− Δ^2_\right]\frac{^2}{^2}$$

Could someone please explain how to do this as I can't find out how to work out the Taylor series

Answer (score 0):

Let us use the notation $U_j^n$ for approximations of $U(x_j, t_n)$ with $x_j = j\Delta x$ and $t_n = n\Delta t$. Using [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), one shows that for smooth solutions
\begin{aligned}
\frac{U_j^{n+1} - \frac12( U_{j+1}^n + U_{j-1}^n )}{\Delta t} &= (U_t)_j^n + \frac{\Delta t}{2}(U_{tt})_j^n - \frac{\Delta x^2}{2\Delta t} (U_{xx})_j^n + O(\Delta t^2, \Delta x^2)
\\
\frac{U_{j+1}^{n} - U_{j-1}^n}{2\Delta x} &= (U_x)_j^n + O(\Delta x^2) .
\end{aligned}
Now let us compute the difference between the PDE and its approximation deduced from the Lax-Friedrichs method. Up to higher-order terms, the scheme produces
$$
\begin{aligned}
(U_t + v_x U_x)_j^n
& - \frac{U_j^{n+1} - \frac12( U_{j+1}^n + U_{j-1}^n )}{\Delta t} - v_x \frac{U_{j+1}^{n} - U_{j-1}^n}{2\Delta x} \\
&= \underbrace{-\frac{\Delta t}{2}(U_{tt})_j^n + \frac{\Delta x^2}{2\Delta t} (U_{xx})_j^n}_\text{l.e.t.}
\end{aligned} $$
Then, the transport equation yields the relationships $U_{tx} = -v_x U_{xx}$ and $U_{tt} = -v_x U_{xt}$ between temporal and spatial derivatives,
which lead to $U_{tt} = v_x^2 U_{xx}$. Finally,
$$
\text{l.e.t} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\Delta x^2}{\Delta t} - \Delta t\, v_x^2\right) (U_{xx})_j^n \, ,
$$
where $j$ and $n$ can be removed.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @EditPiAf: In the first equation, how did you obtain the $O(\Delta t^2, \Delta x^2)$ term? I found that that $\frac{1}{2}(U_{j+1}^n + U_{j-1}^n) = U_j^n + \frac{\Delta x^2}{2} (U_{xx})_{j}^{n} + O(\Delta x^4)$, so my big O term ended up being $\frac{1}{\Delta t} O(\Delta x^4)$...

Comment: @Leonidas I presume [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2796115/418542) cleared your doubts