# Consistency error of Lax-Friedrichs scheme for first order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

This is part of a larger problem regarding the Lax-Friedrichs scheme applied to the PDE $u_t+au_x=0$. I have that the consistency error of the scheme to leading order is
$$
C\Big (\Delta t + \frac{(\Delta x)^2}{\Delta t}\Big)
$$
and we have the CFL number $a\Delta t /\Delta x\leqslant 1$ for stability.

My question is whether we can write the consistency error as $\mathcal{O}((\Delta t)^p+(\Delta x)^q)$ for some $p$, $q$ as large as possible. The error that I have is of course conditional on how the spacings relate, as is the CFL condition, and using the latter, I know the consistency error is
$$
\geqslant \mathcal{O}(\Delta t + \Delta x)
$$
but I'm not sure how we could arrive at a consistency error of the given form.

Any insight would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4029506/418542), one should find that the consistency error of the scheme to leading order is
$$
\frac12 \left(\frac{\Delta x^2}{\Delta t} - a^2\Delta t\right) u_{xx} + \dots
$$
One more assumption is needed to conclude, namely that enforcing a constant Courant number $\Gamma = a \Delta t/\Delta x$ such that $\Gamma \leqslant 1$. This way, we rewrite the local truncation error as
$$
\frac{a \Delta x}2 \frac{1-\Gamma^2}{\Gamma} u_{xx} + \dots = O(\Delta x).
$$

Comment: And since you've enforced proportionality between $\Delta x$ and $\Delta t$, this is the same as $\mathcal{O}(\Delta x + \Delta t)$. Thank you for your answer!